# Security of damaged U2F key?

Tags: recovery, u2f

[U2F key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_2nd_Factor) is praised for its security features. But I am afraid of using something so secure that when it is damaged I couldn't access my own accounts. So I searched what is recovery scenario and for example [Amazon](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_credentials_mfa_lost-or-broken.html) describes it as following:

> if you can't sign in with your MFA device, you can sign in by
> verifying your identity using the email and phone that are registered
> with your account.

Ok, so I could get my data without U2F, but then... the potential intruder would need no U2F too. Avoiding email/phone path was the whole point behind U2F device, right?

My question is as follows -- do I miss something or the case of damaged (true or false) U2F key is actually a weak spot? I mean either recovery is easy for user (and intruder) or it is hard/impossible for user (and intruder)? Are those only two choices, or there is some middle ground, where it is easy for the user but hard for intruder?

Answer (score 1):

In most cases, you can configure OATH-TOTP access as a backup. Sometimes, you can also register more than only one U2F key.